# Cannot access previous response in repository with DHC

Tags: dhc

I use [DHC by Reslet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhc-resthttp-api-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm) a Chrome extension, version 1.2.

When I create a first POST request to create an entity
If I want to access to this request in a another request (repository feature) I cannot access the response.

I have the same problem with DELETE requests, but not for GET requests

Comment: I'm sorry, not sure I got it. Are you asking how to automatically put a value from one request to another one? How to make a reference on a request/response?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure to correctly understand what you want to do but I'll try to give you an answer.

Imagine I want to execute the following:

- **POST request** to add a company using the URL `/companies` and get its identifier from the response
- **GET request** to get the newly created company using the identifier from the previous request

To do that I need to save the first request. I save it with the name `1 - Add company` under the project `Company project` and the service `CRUD service`:

```
Company project
  CRUD service
    1 - Add company
```

Here is what I can use within the second request within its URL field:

```
contactsapi.apispark.net/v1/companies/{"Company project"
    ."CRUD scenario"."1 - Add company".response.body.id}
```

This way DHC will use the value of the `id` field in the response body from the latest executed `1 - Add company` request in the history.